# Spring social integration via JHipster

Tags: spring, jhipster, spring-social

Can someone explain to me how Spring Social works with JHipster. I have BE generated via JHipster and would like to have on my custom Client app Facebook, Gmail, Steam and Discord login ?

Comment: the spring-social tag you have used here links to a useful list of resources https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-social/info  but it does not look easy, see another user's attempt to find help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757438/jhipster-spring-social-principal?rq=1 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463210/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-the-auth-options-for-spring-social-in-j?rq=1

Comment: Hope this will help you. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/02/19/add-social-login-to-spring-boot

Comment: He used oauth2 in this tutorial. But we already have app build with JWT